# How to upgrade db from windows phone 8 to windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have read that SQL CE is not supported on 8.1 universal apps. I have an app published in market place using SQL CE. I want to make this app as universal app. How do I handle upgrade in such scenario?

How do I upgrade SQL CE from silverlight app to SQL lite universal app?? Any ideas?

Comment: 1: Make Silverlght app with sqlite
2: Add Code to migrate data fro SQL CE to SQLite
3: Upgrade app to Universal

Comment: If a user A is on version 1 with sql ce and he doesn't upgrade to version 2 which migrates ce to sql on silverlight but he upgrades to universal instead, then his db wont work. Right?

Comment: Thats right, a catch 22...

Comment: That is very bad. No other way to upgrade DB?

Comment: 1: Add feature in old app to upload user data to cloud service
2: Add feature in new app  (must be new, not update) to download user data from cloud.

Comment: Didn't understand the point where you have mentioned "must be new not update". The new app will always be an update to an older one.

Comment: If the feature 1 in the old app depends on the data access APIs, it will disappear if you Update.

Comment: Hmm.. In my situation, it will update and not install as new. I wish it was new now. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I am saving the data into a file. Since the file will remain in the same format on 8.1. I read the file on 8.1, transform the data into my new model and save it in the new db schema.

I am using CSV library for now, to transform old model data into file.