# database is locked in windows phone 8.1 RT which uses SQLite as database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net, database-locking

I am converting my wp8 app (uses a SQL Server CE database) to a wp8.1RT app (using SQLite database). I am getting an error "database is locked" in the below code.

Sometimes I get the error when retrieving the customers table information, sometimes when deleting it.

I am using different background workers, maybe because of that database is locking.

Can anybody please tell me how to solve this database locking issue?

Do I have to add any extra code or settings?

```
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerTable> RetreiveCheckedCustomer(long customerId)
    {
        var list = new ObservableCollection<CustomerTable>();
        using (SQLiteConnection databasemodel = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            list = new ObservableCollection<CustomerTable>(from item in databasemodel.Table<CustomerTable>() where item.CHECKED == true select item);
            var list2 = new ObservableCollection<LocationTable>(databasemodel.Table<LocationTable>());
            foreach (var item in list2)
            {
                databasemodel.Delete(item);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: any body have an idea how to solve the given problem?

Answer (score 0):

One simply cannot convert wp8 SQL Server CE database to SQLite database for 8.1. Faced the same issue few months back, refer my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864957/how-to-upgrade-db-from-windows-phone-8-to-windows-phone-8-1)

Comment: Hi Milan Aggarwal,Thank you for your reply. Some how I managed to convert the SQL Server CE database to SQLite database.

Comment: Can you share your approach?

Comment: I am able to solve the "database  locked" problem with the below code.

SQLite3.Config(SQLiteConfigOption.MultiThread);

I am able to solve the "database Busy" problem By sharing the SQLiteConnection among multiple background threads and UI thread.

Comment: How are you upgrading sql ce to sqlite?

Comment: I am maintaining two apps.one is WP8 silverlight(using SQL server CE database). Another one is WP8.1 RT(Using SQLite) .Here I am not upgrading existed SQL CE database to SQLite with in a single app.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following line to solve database locked issue.

SQLite3.Config(SQLiteConfigOption.MultiThread);

After that, I have used single SQLite connection through out the app to solve the database busy problem,